# как браузер определяет какой запрос посылать?

Tags: веб-программирование, http

здравствуйте, я разбираюсь в http протоколе... про заголовки, запросы, ответы читал... но не понятен базовый вопрос: есть просто http адрес, допустим, www.google.com, так вот интересует как браузер понимает какой именно http-запрос нужно послать чтобы получить ответ?

Comment: Какой интересный у Вас вопрос по поводу того, *как понять какой послать*. Думаю, что Вам нужно дальше читать про http-запросы. Конечно же, у Google кнопка *Поиск в Google* - это инпут с типом `submit`, но Вы пока видимо не дочитали до таких интересных глубин :)

Comment: Хм. а мне не понятен ваш вопрос. не понятно, чего может быть сложно понятно браузеру. видя адрес www.google.com http запрос будет GET / Host: www.google.com ну и еще стандартные заголовки с датой, информацией о браузере и т.п.

Comment: @Mike, наверное стоит закрыть такой вопрос?

Comment: @DenisBubnov Хз. я предпочитаю не торопиться, вдруг автор вопроса его конкретизирует

Comment: @DenisBubnov, та не, я имел ввиду не когда набираем в поле ввода уже на сайте google.com, а когда тупо в браузере вбиваем www.google.com... ну понятное дело, что он возвращает что-то, что дает keep-alive... но это лишь один ответ... как дальше то происходит взаимодействие? в какой момент мы получаем html страницы самой?

Comment: @xperious, ну вот так и стоило задавать вопрос. Кстати, думаю, что не все браузеры делают это одинаково )

Comment: Вот, прочитайте [статью на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/215117/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Браузер не *понимает*, какой запрос необходимо послать, а *формирует* его.

В тело запроса обозреватель помещает следующую информацию:

1. **Тип и версию используемого протокола** — как правило это `HTTP/1.1`.
2. **Тип запроса** — `GET` для перехода по ссылкам, плюс `PUT` и `POST` для форм.
3. **Имя сайта** — на одном IP-адресе может располагаться (хоститься) несколько сайтов, а потому обозреватель всегда помещает эту информацию.
4. **Путь к запрашиваемой странице** (или файлу, или иному ресурсу) **относительно корня сайта** — когда трава была зелёной, небо голубым, а каждому сайту выделялся отдельный белый адрес, указание имени сайта было необязательным и производилось в дополнительном поле `Host`.
5. **Поддерживаемые возможности** — алгоритмы сжатия, язык системы, поддержка *HTTP2* и так далее.
6. **Ранее переданная сервером информация** — куки, `ETag` и так далее.

Получателя же запроса обозреватель получает с помощью службы DNS. С её помощью он узнаёт, какому IP адресу соответствует имя сайта.

---

> Там, грубо говоря, реализован конечный автомат, который в зависимости от ответа посылает уже другой запрос или как?

Никакого конечного автомата в HTTP нет (это *stateless* протокол). Браузер делает запрос, получает ответ и разрывает подключение, после чего сервер начисто забывает о нас и нашем запросе. Даже при использовании оптимизации *keep-alive* сервер работает с пачкой запросов совершенно независимо.

Поэтому и был придуман механизм *куков*, чтобы клиент мог хоть как-то напомнить о себе серверу, выслав ему в теле запроса *все* куки, полученные из более ранних ответов данного сайта.

Следующий запрос будет произведён только по желанию пользователя, при нажатии ссылки или кнопки отправки формы.

А так, требуется заново отправлять одни и те же заголовки, дублируя их из запроса в запрос. К слову, именно для решения этой проблемы и был придуман `HTTP2`, но это уже совершенно другой протокол.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53506/discussion-on-answer-by-arhad------).